# How to work around rate limits?

Tags: cloud, onedrive

I've been attempting to use Git Annex with the OneDrive API and unfortunately I've been rate limited numerous times when pushing my files.

The Microsoft team has been rather opaque about these limits so I'm wondering:

- Whether traditional methods like exponential falloff are a good way to work around the issue?
- Whether the limits are so low that interacting with the API to upload large amounts of data is worth it at all?

On the latter question, to give a hard number, I've started receiving rate limits at ~1000 requests and 6GiB of data uploaded in an hour. These numbers seem very low to me.

Comment: I'd say that for the end-user product such as OneDrive sending a 1000 requests in an hour is an enormous thing. I can hardly imagine the scenario (besides development ones) which would require the average Joe to send 1000 requests within an hour.

Comment: What if the user wants to upload 1000 100KiB images (old family photos for example)? That's 100MiB and should easily be doable on the average home internet connection. If the API had batch functionality I'd agree with you but it doesn't.

Comment: Well, designers of the service could easily miss such scenario. We can only guess.

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround is to use the BITS endpoint for Onedrive, which also allows very large files to be uploaded to OneDrive. This is a way around the upload limit which you are encountering with the LiveSDKs.

This documentation will be available on MSDN shortly, but until then, here is the doc describing how to make these kinds of requests:
https://gist.github.com/rgregg/37ba8929768a62131e85

Comment: I'll have a look at it but I think the request number is what's causing the limitation at the moment rather than the bandwidth (unless you can confirm that it is the bandwidth). Specifically, creating many nested folders takes a huge number of requests. I put a suggestion for fixing that on UserVoice https://onedrive.uservoice.com/forums/262982-onedrive/suggestions/6710816-allow-interacting-with-folders-by-name-implicit-c